# Impossible to import tensorflow with spyder anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to import tensorflow without success. The installation of each packages is done with Anaconda Navigator or in the Anaconda prompt command with `conda install *package*` in the right env that I've created previously.

For the test I found this script usefull: https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/blog/installation-of-python-spyder-numpy-sympy-scipy-pytest-matplotlib-via-anaconda.html#running-the-tests-with-spyder
and all others packages seems to work.

Something is wrong in the installation of tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Output in the console:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Thanks in advance.

this is the list of what is installed in the env. OS x64
All the solutions in stackoverflow (avx support of the cpu, microsoft c++ 2015, python path) have already been tried

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl
absl-py                   0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     1
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
importlib_metadata        0.19                     py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.8.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
libmklml                  2019.0.5                      0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h7bd577a_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libxgboost                0.90                          0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37hc8f65d3_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.0.2            py37he774522_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
numpy                     1.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37hc3f5095_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1
opt-einsum                3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 19.1                     py37_0
pandas                    0.25.1           py37ha925a31_0
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pip                       19.2.2                   py37_0
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0
protobuf                  3.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
py-xgboost                0.90                     py37_0
py-xgboost-cpu            0.90                     py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
pytz                      2019.2                     py_0
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0
setuptools                41.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0
tb-nightly                1.15.0a20190806          pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37he3c9ec2_0
tensorflow                1.14.0          mkl_py37h7908ca0_0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          mkl_py37ha978198_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
werkzeug                  0.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zipp                      0.5.2                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing spyder again inside the environment was the solution.